# Mysql remote insert

Tags: php, mysql, insert, remote-server

I'm using Mysql and PHP. I have 3 edge servers named A, B, C and a main server D. Every server of ABC exists a table named 'tb_record' to store some records or logs. Now I want ABC gather all the information of 'tb_record' to server D 'tb_allrecord' in realtime(or not to much delay).

For example, once A or B or C insert a record, D also insert the same line(the structure of their table are the same).

Is there any suggestion? I found Master/Slave mode of Mysql did not suitable and trigger did not work on such remote situation.

Thanks for every reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can't achieve via master-slave replication..
you need to write a cronjob for copying the data to D server OR execute the query on both server via your php-code..